# File transfer to RStudio Server

Tags: r, file-upload, server, rstudio-server, writefile

How can I send files from a local computer to a virtual machine with RStudio Studio? Of course, I can use the 'Upload' button but I would like to load something regularly on the virtual machine, how different I can do it?

[image]

Comment: You probably have an IP address and user credentials, use SCP.

Comment: Can you give me any example of use SCP?

Comment: Which OS is running on the VM and on your machine?

Comment: Windows in both cases.

Comment: Usually, SCP communicates on the command line, but there're also GUIs available, e.g. [PuTTY for Windows](https://putty.org/) which you want to install on your machine only. Here you can find some information: https://vipinyadav.com/blog/how-to-use-ssh-and-scp-windows-10-file-folder-upload/

Comment: Since this is an RStudio specific question, you might be better help at https://community.rstudio.com/